# Как сделать в приложении поиск места на карте по пользовательским координатам?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps, leafletjs, mapbox

Пишу учебное задание - веб-приложение-список, в которое пользователь добавляет свои локации с некоторыми свойствами и координатами. Никогда не работал с картами до этого, поэтому поможет любой пинок в нужную сторону. Часть задания, к которой относится вопрос:

> При щелчке по местоположению в списке пользователь может выбрать,
>   увидеть свойства элемента или просмотреть его на фактической карте
>   (используя карты Google или аналогичную. Можно выбирать координаты из
>   службы карт и не вводить вручную.

Подскажите направление, как реализовать эти два пункта (просмотр на карте, и ввод координат из карты)? 
Приложение на React, если это важно (видел в некоторых статьях, что API разняться в зависимости от фреймворка\библиотеки)

Comment: Это все очень легко делается по документации google maps api.
Если вы знакомы с js, то сделать по документации и примерам вам не составит труда.
Это очень просто.
[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Comment: Да, инструкция довольно простая, но, правильно ли я понимаю, там требуется оплата для использования?